# Swift 3 for loop

Tags: swift3

How to convert the following expression to swift 3 code

```
for w = 0; CDay >= month[0][w] + 1; ++w
{
CDay = CDay - month[0][w];
CMonth = w + 2;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without any type information, the only possible solution is using a `while` loop:

```
var w = 0
while CDay >= month[0][w] + 1 {
    CDay -= month[0][w]
    CMonth = w + 2
    w += 1
}
```